# 1970s novel in which an ancient spaceship is unearthed and flies to alien worlds

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

Trying to identify an old paperback:

An alien spaceship is excavated and found to be very old (millions of years?). While investigating, it unexpectedly takes off with a few people aboard. It travels to alien world(s) that are now ancient ruins.

This was a paperback Sci-Fi novel that I read sometime around 1978. I believe the cover had a spherical spaceship.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This really sounds a lot like Andre Norton's *Galactic Derelict*.

- Spherical alien ship. Check.
- Ancient ship. Check.
- Flies to alien worlds which are now ruins. Check.

The only mismatch is that the wreck is discovered in the past using time travel.

The book was first published in 1959 and has been reprinted many times since then. It was certainly in print in 1978.

See the [Wikipedia description of the book.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Derelict)

Covers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first cover is the image that has been rattling around in the back of my brain for decades now. Thank you!